# Custom URL Scheme for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there something similar for the Windows 8 platform to the custom url scheme found on the iOS platform?

I have found [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN about an application URI scheme. This is not the answer.

In my iPad app, the user receives an email with a couple of long keys. The user clicks the url and my app opens to the right page with these values populated. Is there similar functionality available for Windows 8 that I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for protocol activation.

You can add a supported protocol to `Package.appxmanifest` on the `Declarations` tab by adding a `Protocol`. This adds the following block to your `Package.appxmanifest` file:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <Protocol Name="alrt" />
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

You need to handle protocol activation in `App.xaml.cs` by overriding `OnActivated`:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);

    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        var protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

        var rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), protocolArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670%28v=win.10%29.aspx) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. The link at the bottom of your answer states what you said only in slightly more depth.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx).  The [Association launching sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) should provide a sample you can tweak for your own needs.

The Bing Maps app for instance has a [fairly extensive URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx) (not that you can see how they implemented it, of course :))

Comment: O'Niel - Thank-you for your answer. The association launching sample might prove to be useful to someone when they come upon this question. I chose Damir's answer because he put more code into his answer. You both let me know the correct answer.